# Apple-made iOS tutorial help: Unintended overlap with nested Stack Views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I've been following the official Apple-made iOS development tutorial ([located here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1)).  Its a new tutorial, created in December '16, so I haven't been able to find any answers for this question already.  Here is the section I'm stuck on:

> EXPLORE FURTHER
>
> When in editing mode, the rating control extends over the delete
>   button. This is because the cell’s layout was not designed using Auto
>   Layout. The controls fit in the normal allotted space, but the control
>   doesn’t adapt when the space is reduced.
>
> To fix this, you need to lay out the cell using nested stack views and
>   Auto Layout constraints; however, that is left as an exercise for the
>   reader.
>
> For more information, see [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853).

Every attempt I make ends up either compressing right side (5th start) or left side (food picture).

I have two key questions:

1. What is the parent view when the edit button is pressed vs the delete button.  By my (limited) understanding, it seems like behavior is different on the left vs the right side.
2. What is the right direction to head down? My closest solution is as follows: One Stack View for the label and rating system. Then an additional Stack View, wrapping the aforementioned one and the picture.

Source code is available to download at the bottom of the page if anyone wants to tinker with it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd be inclined to make the stars shrinkable, so that if you run out of space, they resize appropriately.

Unfortunately, to do that, you'll have to tweak some code. In particular, you may want to tweak `RatingControl` so the stars will resize gracefully. The current implementation forces their size:

```
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: starSize.height).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: starSize.width).isActive = true
```

I'd suggest changing that so that the size is a "maximum", and merely ensure that the ratio of the width to the height is unchanged.

```
button.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: starSize.height).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: starSize.width).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Or, personally, I think the equivalent `activate` syntax is cleaner:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: starSize.height),
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: starSize.width),
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.heightAnchor)
])
```

You probably should also make the buttons the same size (so I just added the above constraints to the first button and then made all the other buttons have constraints to be the same size and width of the first button).

Then, if you add the appropriate constraints to the cell that call upon the resizing of the rating control, the rating control will be resized gracefully.

Or you can use stack views:

- adding the label and the `RatingControl` to one vertical stack view;
- add that stack view and the image view to a horizontal stack view; and
- add constraints between that stack view and the cell's content view.

Personally, I don't think the stack view approach is much easier than just adding the appropriate constraints, but both approaches work fine. Sometimes stack views make life much, much easier, but I think it's a wash in this case. Your choice.

---

You asked:

> What is the parent view when the edit button is pressed vs the delete button?

The parent view of the image view, the ratings control and the label is the the cell's "content view". This is the content view regardless of whether the cell is in edit mode or not. This is the purpose of the content view, so the overall view hierarchy doesn't have to change when the cell enters or exits edit mode. You can always pause execution in the debugger and use the view debugger button, [image: see stackoverflow.com/a/34447819/1271826], if you ever have questions about what the view hierarchy is at any given point:

[image]

There you can see that the same `UITableViewCellContentView` is in the view hierarchy regardless if the cell is in edit mode or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob, I will try that out!  Did you end up using Stack Views at all like the hint described?

Comment: I didn't, but you certainly can. In some cases, stack views make your life much, much easier. But in this case, it strikes me as a bit of a "six of one, half a dozen of another" scenario. But there's certainly no reason not to use stack views.